# Difference in ZoneDateTime precision between Windows and Unix

Tags: java, windows, unix, jvm

I execute the following code and I got a different precision between Windows and Unix (macOs).

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(ZonedDateTime.now()));
    }
}
```

Output on MacOS (`Darwin Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local 17.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0: Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`) is

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
> java TimeTest 
2018-01-31T11:05:49.59+01:00
```

while on Windows

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

>java TimeTest
2018-01-31T11:02:22.452+01:00
```

Is there an expected output or a bug?

Comment: It was probably `059` milliseconds?

Comment: @BoristheSpider as far as I know `.59` means `59/100 s`  (`=590 ms`) while `.452` means `452 ms`.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't just *happen* to fall on a 10ms boundary on the Mac box?

Comment: My Windows machine will remove unnecessary 0s by the looks of things: e.g. `10:17:09.9Z` then `10:18:02.987Z`, then `10:18:40.79Z`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: No, you guessed that `.59` meant `.059` - the output in my answer shows that it means `.590` (590ms rather than 59ms).

Comment: @JonSkeet and BoristheSpider you are right, however I realize that the different I got is between Java 8 and Java 9 (3 digits compare to 6 digits)

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux: Your original question didn't show 6 digits at all. You've effectively *completely* changed the question, after it was already answered, which is generally a bad idea. I would suggest reverting the question to its original state - if you want to ask a different question (the difference between Java 8 and Java 9) you can do that in a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet indeed it's a better idea [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540070/difference-in-zonedatetime-precision-between-java-8-and-java-9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you just happened to run at an instant where the time was on a 10ms boundary on the Mac.

Here's some sample code to try:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

        String last = "";
        while (true) {
            String next = formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now());
            if (!last.equals(next)) {
                last = next;
                System.out.println(next);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output on my Windows box shows a mixture of output lengths. For example:

```
2018-01-31T10:17:34.589Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.59Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.591Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.592Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.593Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.594Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.595Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.596Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.597Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.598Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.599Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.6Z
2018-01-31T10:17:34.601Z
```

I suspect if you run that code in your various environments, you'll see the same result.

If you need the same length for all output, I think you'll need to specify a custom pattern to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String, Locale)`.

Comment: The implementation strips the zero using `BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros()` as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48540582/1630604).