# Difference in ZoneDateTime precision between Java 8 and Java 9

Tags: java, jvm

I execute the following code and I got a different precision between Java 8 and Java 9.

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(ZonedDateTime.now()));
    }
}
```

Output with Java 8

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
$ java TimeTest
2018-01-31T10:30:49.397Z
```

while with Java 9

```
$ java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
$ java TimeTest
2018-01-31T10:30:02.343193Z
```

Is there an expected output or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc (at least that of java 8) states:

> One to nine digits for the nano-of-second. As many digits will be
>   output as required.

So both are correct.

Furthermore the specification of ISO-8601 states (from Wikipedia):

> There is no limit on the number of decimal places for the decimal fraction.

[Edit]
To be more specific, I dove into debugging Java library code.

The internal representation of the fractional seconds is `397000000` which is then divided and eventually fed into `BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros()` to obtain `.397`.

The reason why Java 9 returns more digits is because in addition to using `System.currentTimeMillis()` which both Java do, Java 9 also calls `VM.getNanoTimeAdjustment()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is an enhancement from Java 9 JSR310, this is described in ticket [JDK-8068730](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730).

> The Java SE 8 specification for java.time.Clock states that "The
>   system factory methods provide clocks based on the best available
>   system clock. This may use System.currentTimeMillis(), or a higher
>   resolution clock if one is available.". In JDK 8 the implementation of
>   the clock returned was based on System.currentTimeMillis(), and thus
>   has only a millisecond resolution. In JDK 9, the implementation is
>   based on the underlying native clock that System.currentTimeMillis()
>   is using, providing the maximum resolution available from that clock.
>   On most systems this can be microseconds, or sometimes even tenth of
>   microseconds.